# How do I use this JQuery Popup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

I'm trying to figure out this JQuery Popup, I can show it on click of "Login" or "Sign Up." But on click of "Login", then on "Sign Up." I want to hide the Login popup and show the Sign Up popup. But it only hides the Login popup and doesn't show the Sign Up popup. How do I fix this?

```css
/* font */

@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);

/* end of font */

/* clear settings */

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: white;
}
/* end of clear settings */

/* nav */

#nav {
  width: 1600px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #1F1F1F;
}
/* end of nav */

/* index.php */

#course_MainTitle {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  position: relative;
  left: 187px;
  top: 20px;
}

#nav_logo {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: relative;
  left: 188px;
  top: 9px;
}

/* Search Engine */

#search_engine {
  background: white;
  color: #353535;
  outline: none;
  width: 500px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  padding: 7px 30px 7px 10px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  position: relative;
  top: 9px;
  left: 210px;
}

#search_engine::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* WebKit, Blink, Edge */
    color:    #353535;
}

#search_engine:-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
   color:    #353535;
   opacity:  1;
}

#search_engine::-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
   color:    #353535;
   opacity:  1;
}

#search_engine:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10-11 */
   color:    #353535;
}

/* End of Search Engine */

/* Login & Sign Up */

#login_nav_div, #signup_nav_div {
  float: right;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #353535;
  font-size: 17px;
  padding: 7px 30px 7px 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  position: relative;
  left: -66px;
  background: white;
  top: 6px;
}

#login, #signup {
  position: relative;
  top: -1px;
  left: 9px;
}

/* End of Login & Sign Up */

/* end of index.php */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title> Hacked Genius </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='main.css'>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src='main.js'></script>
    
    <style>
      /***********************\

 Modal Module - Title CSS FTW

\***********************/
.Modal {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: transparent;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.Modal .content {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 30%;
  width: 390px;
  padding: 50px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #fff;
  transform: translate(-50%, -30%) scale(0);
  z-index: 50;
}
.Modal .close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  right: 8px;
  display: block;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  padding: 2px;
  line-height: 18px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #C5C5C5;
  color: #fff;
}
.Modal .close:before {
  content: '\2715';
}
.Modal.is-visible {
  visibility: visible;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  transition: background .35s;
  transition-delay: .1s;
  z-index: 40;
}
.Modal.is-visible .content {
  transform: translate(-50%, -30%) scale(1);
  transition: transform .35s;
}

/* Model */

#login_title {
   font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
   font-size: 23px;
   letter-spacing: 1px;
   position: relative;
   top: -20px;
   left: 110px;
}

#login_username, #login_password {
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  color: #353535;
  padding: 12px 10px 12px 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-size: 16px;
  position: relative;
  left: -30px;
  width: 425px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

#login_username:focus, #login_password:focus {
  border: 1px solid #4096ee;
}

#login_submit {
/* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#4096ee+0,4096ee+100;Blue+Flat+%232 */
background: #4096ee; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #4096ee 0%, #4096ee 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #4096ee 0%,#4096ee 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #4096ee 0%,#4096ee 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#4096ee', endColorstr='#4096ee',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */

  color: white;
  text-align: center;
 padding: 11px 12px 11px 12px;
  font-size: 22px;
  width: 445px;
  font-weight: normal;
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  float: left;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  left: -28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#login_submit:focus, #login_submit:hover {
  background: rgb(37,141,200);
}


/* End of Model */

/* Error Messages */

#login_username_error, #login_password_error, #login_failed {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #DD4B39;
  position: relative;
  left: -30px;
  top: -8px;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: none;
}

/* End of Error Messages */

/* $_SESSION["id"] set */

#user_avatar {
  float: left;
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  top: -2px;
  left: -10px;
}

#user_username {
  color: white;
  float: right;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
  position: relative;
  top: -31px;
  left: -220px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  padding: 10px;
}

/* Drop Down */

#login_label {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 20px;
}

#login_remember, #login_label {
  position: relative;
  top: 25px;
  left: -30px;
}

#login_label {
  left: -52px;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */
  -webkit-user-select: none;   /* Chrome/Safari/Opera */
  -khtml-user-select: none;    /* Konqueror */
  -moz-user-select: none;      /* Firefox */
  -ms-user-select: none;       /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
  user-select: none;           /* Non-prefixed version, currently
                                  not supported by any browser */
}

a #forgot_password {
  color: black;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  position: relative;
  top: 25px;
  left: 120px;
}

a #forgot_password:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

#login_line {
  background: #ccc;
  height: 1px;
  width: 490px;
  position: relative;
  top: 25px;
  left: -50px;
}

#login_crossSection {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: black;
  position: relative;
  top: 37px;
  left: 90px;
}

#login_crossSection a {
  color: #4096EE;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#login_crossSection a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

/* End of Drop Down */

/* End of $_SESSION["id"] set */

    </style>
  </head>
  
  <body>
    
<!-- Login Popup -->

<div id="Popup" class="Modal">
  <div class="content">
     <span id='login_title'> Welcome Back </span> <br>
     <form action='' method='post'>
      <span id='login_failed'></span>
     <input id='login_username' placeholder='Username' name='login_username'> <br> <br>
     <span id='login_username_error'></span>
     <input id='login_password' placeholder='Password' name='login_password' type='password'> <br> <br>
     <span id='login_password_error'></span>
     <input type='button' value='Login' id='login_submit' onclick='checkErrors()'>
     </form>
     
     <!-- Remember Me -->
     
     <input type='checkbox' name='login_remember' id='login_remember'> <label for='login_remember' id='login_label'> Remember Me </label>
     
     <!-- End of Remember Me -->
     
     <!-- Forgot Password? -->
      <a href='#'> <span id='forgot_password'> Forgot Password? </span> </a> <br> <br>
     <!-- End of Forgot Password -->
     
     <!-- Cross Section -->
     
     <div id='login_line'></div>
     
     
     <span id='login_crossSection'> Not a member yet? <a href='#'> Sign Up </a> </span>
     
     <!-- End of Cross Section -->
     
   <span class="close"></div>
  </div>
  
  <!-- End of Login Popup -->
  
  <!-- Sign Up Popup -->
    <div id="Popup2" class="Modal">
  <div class="content">
     <span id='login_title'> Welcome Hi </span> <br>
     <form action='' method='post'>
      <span id='login_failed'></span>
     <input id='login_username' placeholder='Username' name='login_username'> <br> <br>
     <span id='login_username_error'></span>
     <input id='login_password' placeholder='Password' name='login_password' type='password'> <br> <br>
     <span id='login_password_error'></span>
     <input type='button' value='Login' id='login_submit' onclick='checkErrors()'>
     </form>
     
     <!-- Remember Me -->
     
     <input type='checkbox' name='login_remember' id='login_remember'> <label for='login_remember' id='login_label'> Remember Me </label>
     
     <!-- End of Remember Me -->
     
     <!-- Forgot Password? -->
      <a href='#'> <span id='forgot_password'> Forgot Password? </span> </a> <br> <br>
     <!-- End of Forgot Password -->
     
     <!-- Cross Section -->
     
     <div id='login_line'></div>
     
     <!-- End of Cross Section -->
     
   <span class="close"></div>
  </div>
  <!-- End of Sign Up Popup -->

 <!-- nav -->
      <div id='nav'>
      <a href='index.php'> <span id='nav_logo'> Logo </span> </a>
          
          <!-- Search Engine -->
            <input id='search_engine' placeholder='Search Courses'>
          <!-- End of Search Engine -->
            
            <!-- Sign Up -->
            <a href='#Popup2' class='button'> <div id='signup_nav_div'>
              <span id='signup'> Sign Up </span>
            </div> </a>
            
            <!-- End of Sign Up -->
            
              <!-- Login -->
         
           <a href='#Popup' class='button'> <div id='login_nav_div'>
              <span id='login'> Login </span>
            </div> </a>
            
            <!-- End of Login -->
            } 

            ?>
          
      </div>
    <!-- end of nav -->

  <script>
    
   $.fn.expose = function(options) {

  var $modal = $(this),
    $trigger = $('a[href="' + this.selector + '"]');

  $modal.on("expose:open", function() {

    $modal.addClass("is-visible");
    $modal.trigger("expose:opened");
  });

  $modal.on("expose:close", function() {

    $modal.removeClass("is-visible");
    $modal.trigger("expose:closed");
  });

  $trigger.on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $modal.trigger("expose:open");
  });

  $modal.on("click", function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).is($modal) || $(e.target).is('.close')) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $modal.trigger("expose:close");
    }
  });

  return;
}

// Example Cancel Button

$("#login_nav_div").click(function() {
  $("#Popup").expose();
});

$("#signup_nav_div").click(function() {
  $("#Popup2").expose();
});

$("#login_crossSection a").click(function() {
  $("#Popup").hide();
  $("#Popup2").expose();
});

$(".cancel").on("click", function(e) {
  console.log('a')
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).trigger("expose:close");
});

// Example Callbacks
/*
 $("#Popup").on("expose:opened", function() {

   alert("Modal Opened!");
 });

 $("#Popup").on("expose:closed", function() {

   alert("Modal Closed!");
 });
 */
 
 function checkErrors() {
   
   if($("#login_remember").is(":checked")) {
     var checked = 1;
   } else {
     checked = 0;
   }
   
   var login_username_val = $("#login_username").val().length;
   var login_password_val = $("#login_password").val().length;
   
   var login_username = $("#login_username").val();
   var login_password = $("#login_password").val();
   
   if(login_username_val < 1) {
     $("#login_username_error").show().text("Username Required");
     $("#login_failed").hide();
     $("#login_username").css("border", "1px solid #DD4B39");
   } else {
     $("#login_username_error").hide();
     $("#login_username").css("border", "");
   }
   
   if(login_password_val < 1) {
     $("#login_password_error").show().text("Password Required");
     $("#login_failed").hide();
     $("#login_password").css("border", "1px solid #DD4B39");
   } else {
     $("#login_password_error").hide();
     $("#login_password").css("border", "");
   }
   
   if(login_password_val > 0 && login_username_val > 0) {
     $.post("check.php?checked="+checked, {username: login_username, password: login_password}, function(data) {
       
       if(data == "Login Worked") {
         location.reload();
       }
       
       if(data == "Login Failed") {
         $("#login_failed").show().text("Login Failed");
       }
     });
   }
   
 }

  </script>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to rewrite all of this with the following method in mind. You can greatly simplify your code with it:

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

```
$( "#clickme" ).click(function() {
  $( "#book" ).toggle( "slow", function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
```

> The matched elements will be revealed or hidden immediately, with no
>   animation, by changing the CSS display property. If the element is
>   initially displayed, it will be hidden; if hidden, it will be shown.

Comment: This does not work. Try replacing `expose()` with `toggle()` and you're know what I'm talking about...